# Convert first letters of the first 2 words to Upper using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I know I can do this with awk, but I want to know how to do it with sed.
I know how to convert the first letter of each line to upper:

```
sed  's/^\(.\)/\U\1/' input > output
```

But I want to convert the first letters of the first 2 words to Upper.

Input file:

> this is my file

Output file:

> This Is my file

I think this must be doable with sed, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use `-e` to do two blocks:

```
$ echo "this is my file" | sed -e 's/^\(.\)/\U\1/' -e 's/ \(.\)/ \U\1/'
This Is my file                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   first word          second word
```

Note you can make the lines more clear with the `-r` parameter that allows catching with simple `(XXX)` instead of `\(XXX\)`:

```
$ echo "this is my file" | sed -re 's/^(.)/\U\1/' -e 's/ (.)/ \U\1/' 
This Is my file
```

Comment: You really simplified my life :)

Comment: If you use a word anchor and GNU sed: `sed 's/\<./\U&/1; s/\<./\U&/2'`

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups and `\U` and `\E` to turn on-off the uppercase:

```
sed 's/^\(.\)\([^ ]* \)\(.\)/\U\1\E\2\U\3/' input > output
```

or

```
sed -r 's/^(.)([^ ]* )(.)/\U\1\E\2\U\3/' input > output
```

Quoting from [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> `\U`
>
> ```
> Turn the replacement to uppercase until a \L or \E is found
> ```

As an example:

```
$ echo 'this is my life' | sed 's/^\(.\)\([^ ]* \)\(.\)/\U\1\E\2\U\3/'
This Is my life
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not asked for `awk`, but posting a general solution if other are interested.

```
echo "this is my file" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=2;i++) sub(".",substr(toupper($i),1,1),$i)}1'
This Is my file
```

It can easily be change to n number of words, and if you like the two first letter of a word to be changed:

```
echo "this is my file" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=2;i++) sub("..",substr(toupper($i),1,2),$i)}1'
THis IS my file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, perl

```
perl -ane '@F[0,1] = map {ucfirst} @F[0,1]; print "@F"'
```